# Routing for static site causes endless loading in browser when readFile() is in an if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, routes

I am trying to create routing for a static site however placing readFile() in an if statement causes infinite loading in my browser and content doesn't load.
I'm trying to do this without the use of Express or any similar framework.

Here is my code:

```js
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var url = require("url");
var path = require("path");

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let parsedURL = url.parse(req.url, true);

  let fPath = parsedURL.path;

  if (fPath === "/") {
    fPath = "/index.html";
  }
  file = path.join(__dirname, "/public" + fPath);

  if (fPath === "/index.html") {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.end("An error has occured.");
      } else {
        res.end(data);
      }
    });
  } else if (fPath === "/information.html") {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.end("An error has occured.");
      } else {
        res.end(data);
      }
    });
  }
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: You are returning, but you don't send anythin

Comment: Excuse me, I edited it. This was due to the if statements being in a function.

Comment: Browsers will often request more than what's in your URL, eg.  favicon, and as been pointed out your not handling unknown requests, you should be at least sending 404, and 500 for errors.  IOW:  `res.end` at some point want's sending, no matter what the request is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `if (fPath === "/index.html") {` matches and `fs.readFile` has an error, then **you don't send a response**.

The same is true for `"/information.html"`.

And if `fPath` isn't either of those then you get to the end and **you don't send a response**.

---

The endless loading is caused by the browser waiting for a response you never send.

You need to make sure that **every** path through your `if` statements calls `res.end` or another function that sends a response to the browser.

Comment: I am still experiencing the same issue, even when sending a response through each if and else statement.

Comment: @Dark_Rabbit  So what response are you sending for `/bobsyouruncle.html`

Comment: @Keith I understand what you mean now. I have to create responses for other files that might be getting loaded through `index.html` or `information.html`. Thank you.

Comment: @Dark_Rabbit  Yes, that and files that don't exist. just put a final else statement that sends an error message.  I would also use status code 404 for this too,.. eg.  `else { res.status(404); res.end('Page not found'); }`  Because like I mentioned in other comments, the browser at some point will ask for a favicon even if you don't have one in your html, and of course hackers and bots + miss types could request anything.. :)